# Struts 2 - Malformed OGNL expression: {1}() Encountered " ")" (blank expression)

Tags: jsp, struts2

We have a Struts 2 application which occasionally fails with the following error when performing an action from a page, and I am seeking ways on how to debug this:

```
ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression: {1}() 
[ognl.ParseException: Encountered " ")" ") "" at line 1, column 5. 
Was expecting one of: ":" ... "not" ... "+" ... "-" ... "~" ... "!" ... "("       
... "true" ... "false" ... "null" ... "#this" ... "#root" ... "#" ... "[" 
... "{" ... "@" ... "new" ... ... ... "\'" ... "`" ... "\"" ... ... ... ] at 
ognl.Ognl.parseExpression(Ognl.java:112) at
```

`com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:442) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:396) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:430) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:290) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:251) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) at` `com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:168) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245) at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:76) at`

It looks like an Action Name isn't getting filled properly from a `{1}`.

Occasionally this happen when the page is idle for too long, and a button is clicked, but sometimes there is no timeout.

There is no easy way to debug or investigate, any tips? This can't be reproduced consistently.

Comment: There's no way to help with the information provided. You need to up the logging game so you can at least determine what type(s) of requests generate the error.

Comment: It seems an ognl hack. You need to hire admin to check the logs and a developer to debug your application. As is looks like off-topoc question it should be closed appropriately.

Comment: What kind of logging? Struts' AuthorizationInterceptor for every action already picks up the unexpanded `{1}` rather than an action name, so server-side logging is useless here.

Comment: This would be inside Struts which we can't audit. The issue is in expanding {1} into an Action Name, which isn't happening correctly. Any thoughts on how to proceed on this?